# Direct sum of subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ is a Borel map - Self study

Tags: abelian-groups, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Let $\mathcal{Pow}(\mathbb{Q}^n)$ be the power set of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and consider the product topology induced by the natural bijection $\mathcal{Pow}(\mathbb{Q}^n)\cong 2^{\mathbb{Q}^n}$ defined by $A\mapsto \chi_A$.
Hence the induced ("product") topology on $\mathcal{Pow}(\mathbb{Q}^n)$ is generated by the basic open sets of the form $\mathcal{O}_{F,\,G}=\{S\in\mathcal{Pow}(\mathbb{Q}^n)\mid F\subseteq S,\,S\cap G=\emptyset\}$, where $F,\,G\subseteq \mathbb{Q}^n$ are finite.
Assume $R(\mathbb{Q}^n)$ denotes the set of all subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ of rank $n$. It is clearly equipped with the relative topology.

I want to prove the following:

"Let $f\colon R(\mathbb{Q}^n)\to R(\mathbb{Q}^{n+1})$ be the map defined by $f(A)=A\oplus \mathbb{Q}$. Show that it is Borel."

Here is my attempt: let $\mathcal{O}_{F,\,G}\cap R(\mathbb{Q}^{n+1})$ be a (nonempty) basic open subset of $R(\mathbb{Q}^{n+1})$. I want to show that 
$$f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_{F,\,G}\cap R(\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}))=\{A\in R(\mathbb{Q}^{n})\mid F\subseteq (A\oplus\mathbb{Q}),\, (A\oplus\mathbb{Q})\cap G=\emptyset\}$$ is Borel.
Now, if $\pi\colon\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{Q}^n$ is the projection on the first $n$ components, then the following should hold: $F\subseteq (A\oplus\mathbb{Q})$ iff $\pi(F)\subseteq A$.
In a similar way $(A\oplus\mathbb{Q})\cap G=\emptyset$ iff $A\cap \pi(G)=\emptyset$.

Then $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_{F,\,G}\cap R(\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}))=\{A\in R(\mathbb{Q}^n)\mid \pi(F)\subseteq A,\,A\cap \pi(G)=\emptyset\}$ is open.
In other words, if this is the case, $f$ is also continuous.

Is my attempt correct? I think I'm missing something because otherwise continuity should have been stated explicitly.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: After a quick glance it looks OK to me.

Comment: Thank you for your time and comment :-)